# activeClassName dose not work when clicking on the link

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying a lot to change the style the active link , but still didn't work!

This is my code ?
 in Nav.js

```
import { NavHashLink as NavLink } from "react-router-hash-link";
<li>
              <NavLink
                exact
                className="link"
                to="#start"
                activeClassName="selected"
              >
                Start
              </NavLink>
              <span> /> </span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink
                exact
                to="#work"
                className="link"
                activeClassName="selected"
              >
                Work
              </NavLink>
              <span> /> </span>
            </li>
```

in App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

  <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Start />
        <Work />
  </Router>
    </div>
```

any help please!?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new can you uplaod your code here , and  i will fix it 100%

Comment: Can i send  you the link of  github?

Comment: sure send it gimme

Comment: https://github.com/amanihaki/My-Portfolio-test   this is the link

Comment: your folder is empty *_*

Comment: Where is the part in the code where you try to change the style of active link?

Comment: In App.css.....